# How to set SortDescriptions of CollectionView in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting

I have defined SortDescriptions and GroupDescriptions in XAML.

```
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DefaultGrouping" Source="{Binding Projects}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="ProjectName" Direction="Ascending" />
                <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="CreationDate" Direction="Descending"/>
                <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="LastUsedTime" Direction="Descending"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Default"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
```

And now I want to change the SortDescriptions in the code of my viewmodel. But with following code I get an empty ListCollectionView.

`CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Projects);`

Is there any way to get the right CollectionView?

Comment: Have you tried naming the `CollectionViewSource` and then referring to it by name?

Comment: Projects is a IDynamicViewModelCollection<IProjectViewModel> and a Property of my viewmodel , but could possibly be any kind of List.